# Adding rows to MySQL db and showing DIVs with jQuery without refreshing a page

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am using some PHP script to add some data from a complex form to MySQL db and then showing it all in some HTML table. Everything works just fine, but I would like to 'upgrade' my script with jQuery and (I suppose) AJAX.

What I would like to do is when user submits data, the row (or `<div>`) shows up in the HTML table without refreshing a page. Form and table are on same page, of course...

Some guidelines would be really helpful because I'm not sure should I even use AJAX or something else for my needs. Links for some tutorials will be also great :)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used [this tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/comment-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html) to implement a comment system on one of my projects. It uses ajax and works really well. I believe that this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is using jQuery POST method

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

When the user submits the data, you use jQuery to post the data to a PHP handler, which saves the data to the database and returns a HTML formatted row to add to your table.

Here's a good example:
http://www.jensbits.com/2009/10/04/jquery-ajax-and-jquery-post-form-submit-examples-with-php/comment-page-1/

Comment: Thanks for those links too! :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need:

- A php page where to submit the form. Ideally this page will return the result as a JSON object (PHP has some handy JSON functions to convert PHP arrays and objects directly to a proper JSON string). Don't forget to include some error information in the JSON object you return. This can have the form:

  { 
    "errorCode": 0, 
    "result": 
    { 
      "var1": value1, 
      "var2": value2 
    } 
  }
- Some javascript to submit the form. This can be done nicely with `jQuery.ajax`, `jQuery.post` or `jQuery.get` functions.
- Some javascript to handle the result from the PHP script. This will be a callback function that you give to the `jQuery.ajax`, `jQuery.post` or `jQuery.get` functions. This script will either:

  - display the errors to the user (you can set some text in a div for example using `jQuery("#error").html("My error message");`)
  - Insert the row in your table. You can build HTML elements dynamically using `jQuery.append` and `jQuery.html` functions.