# Populate array for jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

I have 2 fields on the form, Fruits and FruitVarieties.

I need to populate an Array based on the Fruit value. This array is then used to AutoComplete Fruit Varieties. The array values are selected from a MySQL DB using Perl. What is the best way to populate this array using jQuery/AJAX?

Comment: google the `jQuery Autocomplete` logic

Answer (score 1):

This example of jquery autocomplete with perl may get you started: http://www.jensbits.com/2011/05/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-perl-and-mysql/

Comment: The link appears to be dead at the moment - what did it say?

Comment: @RowlandShaw the link is fine. Just loaded it.

Answer (score -1):

You need a script on the server that will output the fruit varieties in JSON format given a fruit. This script will be used by an autocomplete plugin for jQuery (such as jQuery UI autocomplete for instance)

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194695/adding-rows-to-mysql-db-and-showing-divs-with-jquery-without-refreshing-a-page/5194878#5194878) for some links and explanations.

Comment: I have a Perl script on the server that returns an array of hashes from the database. How do I convert it to JSON fromat (the array has an Id, Name)

Comment: Look for the autocomplete plugin and see the format it expects.